# Scaling function for axis in d3 disappears on recall

Tags: d3.js

I am writing a subroutine using d3 to draw and redraw a stacked bar chart. My starting point is Bostock's example Stacked Bar Chart, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208. My problem is that the first time I call the routine everything works as expected, but the second time it gets called (e.g. for a resize) an error occurs in the code below; the scaling function y() ceases to exist.

```
state.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })     // Parsing error
.attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

Debugging shows that inside the function call in

```
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
```

the function y suddenly becomes undefined and the return value y(d.y1) thus nonexistent.

I have written other subroutines based on d3 examples and not had any problems with calling them repeatedly (for scaling purposes). Can someone offer a way around this or explain what is happening in the code?

---

Further details: Below is a complete example which you can run. The subroutine is called twice, but the second time it fails do plot the data. The parsing error occurs in line 77.

A complete example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>
.axis, .legend { font: 10px sans-serif;}
.axis path, .axis line { fill: none; stroke: #000; shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
.bar { fill: steelblue;}
</style>
<script>
function createStackedBarChart(division, data, x_data, group_name, y_label, yTic){
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== x_data; }));
data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
});
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50},
    width = parseInt(d3.select(division).style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = parseInt(d3.select(division).style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .nice();
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
    if (yTic == "s") {
        formatValue = d3.format(".2s");
        yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return formatValue(d)});
    }
    if (yTic == "%") yAxis.ticks(10, "%");
var svg = d3.select(division).append("svg")
    .attr("style", "width: 100%;height: 100%;")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[x_data]; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
var x_label = x_data;
if (group_name) x_label = x_label + " / " + group_name;
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("x", width/2 )
        .attr("y", margin.bottom-6)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(x_label);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ (-margin.left) +","+(height/2)+")rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(y_label);

var selGrp = "."+x_data;
var group = svg.selectAll(selGrp)
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d[x_data]) + ",0)"; });

group.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="Chart" style="width:60vw;height:40vh;"></div>
<script>
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    createStackedBarChart("#Chart", data, "State", "Age", "Population", "s");
    createStackedBarChart("#Chart", data, "State", "Age", "Population", "s");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The data:

> ```
> State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64 Years,65 Years and Over
> CA,2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496
> TX,2027307,3277946,1420518,2454721,7017731,5656528,2472223
> NY,1208495,2141490,1058031,1999120,5355235,5120254,2607672
> FL,1140516,1938695,925060,1607297,4782119,4746856,3187797
> IL,894368,1558919,725973,1311479,3596343,3239173,1575308
> PA,737462,1345341,679201,1203944,3157759,3414001,1910571
> ```

Comment: Sounds like you've declared `y` in the wrong scope.

Comment: You haven't shown enough code for us to help.  You need to show enough code to reproduce the problem....

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added a complete code example to demonstrate the problem.